# Reimplementing start() of QThread

Tags: c++, qt

I am practicing threads in Qt. I reimplemented `run()` (though it is not recommended) and everything worked fine.

Now I want add some more functionality to `run()` by letting it pass a variable: `run(int i)`.
Furthermore I want `start()`, which calls run, to pass a variable to `run(int i)`: `start(int j)`.

I thought reimplementing start in the following way should work:(Zaehler is the QThread)

`void Zaehler::start(int ZaehlerIndex)
{
    run(ZaehlerIndex),
    terminate();
}`

Well it doesn't. My GUI freezes upon starting the thread.

**Question:**
I know, messing with start and run should be avoided, but is there a way to do this? Am I doing something wrong?

Remark:
I looked up qthread.cpp to see how `start()` is implemented but all i found was

`\sa run(), terminate()` which is commented out! So it actually shouldn't even work!?

Comment: have you solved your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
class Worker
{
    //note, only pass parameters by copy here.
    public: 
        Worker(int param) : myParam(param) {}

    public slots:
        void process()
        {
            //do something with myParam here, it will run in the thread.
        }

    signals:
        void finished();
        void error(QString err);

    private:
        int myParam;
};
```

Which can then be hooked up to a thread object using "moveToThread" like so:

```
QThread* thread = new QThread;
Worker* worker = new Worker(5);
worker->moveToThread(thread);
connect(worker, SIGNAL(error(QString)), this, SLOT(errorString(QString)));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(process()));
connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
thread->start();
```

See here for more info and a short tutorial on thread usage in Qt:
http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to start a function inside thread and pass some arguments this function I'd recommended this method:

```
class MyWorker: public QThread
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyWorker()
    {
        start();
    }

    virtual ~MyWorker()
    {
        quit();
        wait();
    }

    // your function to call inside thread
    Q_INVOKABLE void doSomeWork(int data)
    {
        // check if we called from another thread
        if (QThread::currentThread() != this)
        {
            // re-call self from very own thread
            QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "doSomeWork",
                                      Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection,
            // or Qt::QueuedConnection if you want to start it asynchronously
            //  and don't wait when work finished
                                      Q_ARG(int, data));
            return;
        }

        // this will be started within your thread
        // some useful work here
    }
};
```

If your thread have no run() method QEventLoop will be used and you can recall your method within thread context.

Also instead of Q_INVOKABLE you can declare your method as slot and call it using queued connection.